# Android - Saving image into SD Card through AsyncTask fails

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-bitmap

I have images in my drawables folder. Activity opens them, I choose the needed images and click on button. They must be saved on my SD Card through `ImageSavingTask` class instance execution which extends `AsyncTask`.

[image: Here's what my MainActivity looks like.]

Here is my `onClick` code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
            imageIndex = new ImageIndex(); //ImageIndex-a class with single index field which reserves the checked checkbox indexes.
            imageIndex.index = i;
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) (images[i].getDrawable())).getBitmap();
            SaveImageTask saveImageTask = new SaveImageTask();
            saveImageTask.execute(bitmap); //The class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void>
        }
}
```

Then the selected images are handled in `doInBackground` method.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
            dir.mkdirs();

            String fileName = "Saved image " + imageIndex.index; //The reserved index of checkbox creates a name for the new file.
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream.write(imageBytes);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` line is added in my manifest.

After I connect the USB to my phone, no error happens, but no images are saved to my SD Card. And I can't find images on my phone using windows search. Debugging doesn't give any answer. What kind of problem this could be?

[image: No errors on debug]

Comment: `SaveImageTask saveImageTask = new SaveImageTask();` You should give the index to the task directly. Not in a global as you do now as all tasks will get the same. Better: `SaveImageTask saveImageTask = new SaveImageTask(i);`.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`. You are not saving to a SD card but to external storage.

Comment: You should use a File Explorer app on your device to check if the images are there. Indeed you will not see them with your PC as you did not inform the MediaStore about the new files. If indeed the files are created you will see them on your PC after switching off/on your device.

Comment: How to detect exactly the SD Card?

Comment: Well that is of later concern. You first could react to all the other things i said and get your code running.

Comment: Changing the Bitmap to Integer requires doInBackground to initialize
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) (images[i].getDrawable())).getBitmap() in doInBackground method, but getDrawable is a UI method and cannot be called in doInBackground.
I changed params to Void, initializing bitmap in onPreExecute and still no changes.

Comment: You still did not react to the things i said. And what you said does not make sense as the bitmap is a parameter for doInBackground.

Comment: The coding was normal. I noticed that the pictures appear only after I restart my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the selected indexes into 2 ArrayLists of indexes and bitmaps. In the `doInBackground` method I created a loop.

For appearing the images on the card immediately I used the `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
        index.add(i);
        bitmap.add(bitmaps[i]);
    }
if (bitmap.size() > 0)
    new SaveImageTask().execute();
```

The `doInBackground` method:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    fname = "Saved image " + (index.get(i)) + ".jpg";
                    file = new File(myDir, fname);
                    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    MediaScannerConnection.
                            scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I left the `ImageSavingTask` without fields and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not asked runtime permissions for writing file on SD Card. From Android M and above you need to ask write permission at runtime to save any file on external sd card.

Check this link on how to request runtime permissions- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Also you can use google library - https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
to request permissions.

Comment: I have 5.0 version API 21

Comment: Yes, both write and read permissions.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename.myappname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application ...

Answer (score 0):

I think problem where you try to write bytes.

Use Following Solution..

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
      Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
      saveToInternalStorage(bitmap, "MyImage"); // pass bitmap and ImageName
      return null;
}

//Method to save Image in InternalStorage
private void saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String imageName) {

            File mypath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), imageName + ".jpg");

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

**NOTE :** Make sure you have added storage read/write permission and don't forget to ask permission on Marshmallow and higher version.